# Parse JSON string with Excel to search field values (price)

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I need to extract `price` value from this cell after the `old_value` and the `new_value` from the following JSON string in cell `A1`:

```
{"createdAt": "1671062337000", "lastModifiedAt": "1671062337000", 
"item_id": "108532709", "old_value": {"variants": {"946038674": 
{"choice_groups": {"108532709": {"choices": {"946038818": 
{"price": "186.55"}}}}}}}, "closedAt": "1671062337000", 
"new_value": {"variants": {"946038674": {"choice_groups": {"108532709": 
{"choices": {"946038818": {"price": "190.55"}}}}}}}, 
"type_of_change": "EmbeddedChoicesPriceChange"}
```

Here is the same JSON string as before but just in a single line so you can copy and paste:

```
{"createdAt": "1671062337000", "lastModifiedAt": "1671062337000", "item_id": "108532709", "old_value": {"variants": {"946038674": {"choice_groups": {"108532709": {"choices": {"946038818": {"price": "186.55"}}}}}}}, "closedAt": "1671062337000", "new_value": {"variants": {"946038674": {"choice_groups": {"108532709": {"choices": {"946038818": {"price": "190.55"}}}}}}}, "type_of_change": "EmbeddedChoicesPriceChange"}
```

I was trying to use:

```
MID(A2, FIND(CHAR(1),SUBSTITUTE(A2,"-",CHAR(1),2))+1, 
FIND(CHAR(1),SUBSTITUTE(A2,"-",CHAR(1),3)) - 
FIND(CHAR(1),SUBSTITUTE(A2,"-",CHAR(1),2))-1)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
=LET(t,TEXTSPLIT(A1,,HSTACK(CHAR(1)&"""",""""),1),
     o,XMATCH("old_value",t),
     n,XMATCH("new_value",t),
--INDEX(t,VSTACK(o,n)+16),)
```

TEXTSPLIT is used to split the text on either `CHAR(1)` or `"`. This returns a spill range of the splitted values.

`o` searches for the string `old_value` in this spill array and returns it's position.

`n` searches for the string `new_value` in the spill array and returns it's position.

Both prices are found 16 "rows" below in the spill array.

INDEX / VSTACK+16 returns the old and new price spilled and `--` converts the string to numeric value.

[image]

Comment: could you please clarify more?

Comment: See update for explanation. Office 365is required.

Answer (score 0):

You can combine `TEXTBEFORE` with `TEXTAFTER` if such functions are available in your excel version and assuming `price` field appears two times as the question indicates. Put the following formula in `B4`:

```
=TEXTBEFORE(TEXTAFTER(A1,"{""price"": """, {1;2}),"""")
```

here is the output:

[image: output excel file]

If you want to return the result by column, then replace `{1;2}` with `{1,2}`.

For your convenience you can define a user `LAMBDA` function `TEXTBETWEEN`, and reuse it:

```
=LET(TEXTBETWEEN, LAMBDA(text,before,after,occ,
  TEXTBEFORE(TEXTAFTER(text,after,occ), before)),
  TEXTBETWEEN(A1, """", "{""price"": """, {1;2})
)
```

Based on JSON structure (using [Online JSON viewer](http://jsonviewer.stack.hu/)), we have two records only: `old_value`, `new_value` and the `price` field appears only inside such records. Assuming no other records types are presents with `price` information, there is no need to verify the `price` belongs only to such records.

[image: JSON file]